# foreach inside foreach to combine two mysql queries results

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

my queries generate two results like

Then i have tried pulling results with two arrays with two while loops

```
while ($rowPost = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grabPostsQuery)) { 
  $posts[] = $rowPost;            
}
while ($rowComment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grabCommentsQuery)) {
   $comments[] = $rowComment;
}

$grabPostsQuery = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY postDate DESC";
$grabPostsQuery = mysqli_query($link, $grabPostsQuery);
$grabCommentsQuery = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY commentDate DESC";
$grabCommentsQuery = mysqli_query($link, $grabCommentsQuery);
```

Then i made a nested foreach like as it follows

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
   foreach($comments as $comment) {
       echo $post['postContent']."<br>";
       echo $comment['commentContent']."<br>";
   }
}
```

I can access both posts and comments the only problem is that foreach loop loops multiple times through posts and comments then displaying them twice

Any HELP PLEASE?

Comment: Why not use a JOIN?

Comment: how to JOIN displaying results are indesiderate because ordering is not as expected

Comment: use JOIN here ..

Comment: I don't what indesiderate means. Sounds like a Trumpism (or Bushism)

Comment: already used join and ordering results was a mess

Comment: Dude, I think you are better off pulling comments for each post, using the ID for post to get comments for that post, that way you have a cleaner fetched result

Comment: ok they have something in common now i added a column in comments with post respective id

Comment: Check my answer in a bit

Comment: @DuduClau I think showing us your sample database structure i.e tables would be more helpful to supplement your code.

Comment: I hope that answered your question, thanks for the accept, an upvote would be nice too :D

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run your loops singularly, not one inside the other...:

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
  echo $post['postContent']."<br>";
}
foreach($comments as $comment) {
  echo $comment['commentContent']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: i need them combined how do i do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by combined? From the queries you show, the posts table and the comments table could be completely unrelated... I suppose you should refactor your SQL a bit... :-)  
To start with, find whhich fields *link* the two tables (if any)...

Comment: yes they have nothing in common i want to display results mixed

Comment: he wants his query to use something like a join query that joins post and comments

Comment: please give an join example and then can grab posts date content id and comments date content ids